# How do you correctly cluster document names & find similarities between documents based on Word2Vec model?

Tags: python, nlp, cluster-analysis, word2vec

I have a set of documents (3000) which each contain a short description. I want to use Word2Vec model to see if I can cluster these documents based on the description.

I'm doing it the in the following way, but I am not sure if this is a "good" way to do it. Would love to get feedback.

I'm using Google's trained w2v model.

```
wv = gensim.models.KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format('GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin.gz',binary=True,encoding="ISO-8859-1", limit = 100000)
```

Each document is split into words where stop words are removed, and I have used stemming as well.

My initial idea was to fetch the word vector for each word in each documents description, average it, and then cluster based on this.

```
doc2vecs = []
for i in range(0, len(documents_df['Name'])):
    vec = [0 for k in range(300)] 
    for j in range(0, len(documents_df['Description'][i])):
        if documents_df['Description'][i][j] in wv:
            vec += wv[documents_df['Description'][i][j]]
    doc2vecs.append(vec/300)
```

I'm then finding similarities using

```
similarities = squareform(pdist(doc2vecs, 'cosine'))
```

Which returns a matrix of the cosine between each vector in `doc2vec`.

I then try to cluster the documents.

```
num_clusters = 2
km = cluster.KMeans(n_clusters=num_clusters)
km.fit(doc2vecs)
```

So basically what I am wondering is:

Is this method of clustering the average word vector for each word in the document a reasonable way to cluster the documents?

Comment: In my experience this doesn't work well. Document similarity is not what the vectors are trained for. Good luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In 2019, unless you have serious resource constraints, you don't need to vectorize documents by averaging word embeddings. You can use Universal Sentence Encoder to vectorize documents [in a few lines of code](https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder/2).

Most clustering algorithms do better in low dimensions, so from here you want to do dimensionality reduction, then clustering. AFAIK, you'll get the best results from UMAP. [Their docs](https://umap-learn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/clustering.html) explain how to do this very clearly.

Comment: Thank you, I will look into this! Do you have any input regarding what metric to use for document similarity after using USE? Cosine similarity?

Comment: Well, you can if you want to make that similarities matrix

Comment: Thank you. I tried using KmeansClustering on the USE encoded vectors by using dimensionality reduction (tried both SVD and UMAP). With SVD I did not get any clear clusters, but with UMAP I did get it. What does that mean in practice? I also tried finding document similarity with TFIDF, then I managed to get 2 clear clusters using SVD and KMeansClustering. Not sure if that means that the USE is not good for this case for me.

Comment: I'm the link, UMAP explains why you might want to use HDBSCAN for clustering